# How it works - image.setUrl in gwt?

Tags: gwt

The image in the carImageView is loaded dynamically, there is recieved a response from db with url of picture and then is called setUrl(url).

Next: I want to do some operation(method foo()) that depended on current image. So, I can handle the event "onLoad" and place my method foo() in this handler. But if a new loaded image identical to last image, this event is not happened (why?).

The heart of the problem - if I place method foo() right after the calling image.setUrl(url), is it possible, that image hasn`t loaded yet  and hasn`t rendered in the carImageView , but method foo() has already done? How can I avoid this things?

PS sry for my English.

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

    showLoadingPanel();
    try {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                final int code = response.getStatusCode();
                final String text = response.getText();
                if (code == 200) {
                    if (response.getHeader("Content-Type").contains("text/html") &&
                        text.contains("<meta name=\"login\"/>")) {
                        Window.Location.reload();
                        return;
                    }

                    String img = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + text;

                    cameraImage.setUrl(img);
                    foo();

                    hideLoadingPanel();

                } else {
                    showImageNotFoundError();
                    hideLoadingPanel();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable e) {
                eventBus.fireEvent(new ServerRequestFailureEvent(e, this.getClass()));
                hideLoadingPanel();
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        eventBus.fireEvent(new ServerRequestFailureEvent(e, this.getClass()));
        hideLoadingPanel();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Are you using IE and is your iamge larger than 32K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just defer the call to `foo()` (using [`Scheduler#scheduleDeferred()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29)):

```java
cameraImage.setUrl(img);
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
   @Override
   public void execute() {
      foo();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems in the past, the [gwt-image-loader](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-image-loader/) project solved it for me!

To solve your problem:

```
FitImage image = new FitImage();
image.addFitImageLoadHandler(new FitImageLoadHander() {
    public void imageLoaded(FitImageLoadEvent event) {
        if (!event.isLoadFailed()) {
            foo();
        }
    }
});
image.setUrl("data:image/jpeg;base64," + text;);
```

Now `foo()` will only be run after the image is loaded. Take a look at the project, things like `ImagePreloader` come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

I place the calling cameraImage.setUrl("") after showLoadingPanel(). Now I can handle the onLoad event even a new image is identical to last image.
It helps me and I think it is more easier and maybe better decision than others.